# Paypal Billing Agreement IPN

Tags: php, laravel, paypal

I use Paypal PHP SDK especially Billing Plan & Agreements. There is a package on Github with some samples.

I've created [this method](http://pastebin.com/ErR2ekgU) for creating a billing plan and a billing agreement, and [this method](http://pastebin.com/a4mnV0aC) for IPN listener, I guess...

Is is the second method good as IPN listener? I want to know if the customer pays me on every month and I want to update `subscription_ends_at` column with 1 month on every IPN calling.

I don't know how to test this IPN. When I pay with Sandbox email, the script redirect me on the second method and then I have possibility to get and save a unique ID in database. But I don't know if Paypal it uses the same IPN when someone Cancel my subsciption.

Paypal call IPN just when a customer Cancel, Suspend a payment, or for every month?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you solved it? It's working?